# Selenium::WebDriver::Error::SessionNotCreatedError: from action in github (in vscod works good)

Tags: iframe, rspec, capybara

2022-03-08 11:21:22 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] [:driver_path] Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome#driver_path= is deprecated. Use Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Service#driver_path= instead.

An error occurred while loading spec_helper.
Failure/Error: browser = Capybara.current_session.driver.browser

Selenium::WebDriver::Error::SessionNotCreatedError:
session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 99
Current browser version is 98.0.4758.102 with binary path /usr/bin/google-chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message explains exactly what your issue is - You're using chromedriver v99.x with Chrome v98.x -- that won't work.  Rather than trying to manually manage the version of chromedriver being used, just use the `webdrivers` gem to automatically manage it for you.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I removed chromedriver-helper. And its work  good for me